# how to wrap float div around absolute position divs?

Tags: css, dynamic, height, css-position

I have a floated div (has a background color) with JS slideshow inside it
this slideshow generated content with absolute position , how can I get the parent div to wrap around it 
I can't set a static height for the div

any advice please

thanks